# Как отправить сообщение видимое только одному человеку в discord.py?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

С помощью какого метода можно отправить сообщение видимое только тому кто прописал команду в discord.py? А остальные это сообщение не видят.

Comment: тип эфемерное сообщение?

Comment: @RAINGM типо сообщение которое "Это сообщение видно только вам | Скрыть"

Comment: это discord.ui, у вас должен быть `discord py 2.0` или его форк типа `nextcord` `pycord` `disnake` и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

В библиотеке discord.py такого нет
Но в библиотеке discord components есть метод respond

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]